# Running ubuntu bash in windows 10 from python script

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu, windows-10

I'm using Ubuntu bash subsystem in windows 10, and I want to open it through  a python script.

This is my code :

```
import os
os.system('bash')
```

but I'm getting this error:

> 'bash' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Comment: Does typing `bash` in a CMD window works? If not then it won't work through Python as well, unless you use `os.path.append` before calling `os.system` (which is deprecated and shouldn't be used, use `subprocess.Popen` instead).

Comment: `os.system` is using `cmd.exe` to execute the string you pass; you should try using the `subprocess` module anyway instead of `os.system`.

Comment: it does work when I type bash in CMD   
@DeepSpace